# Nested SQL Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to learn SQL and trying to write a SQL Query that does the following:

I have two tables:

```
SalaryRangeTable: id, beginRange, endRange
UserInfoTable: id, salary, ...
```

I want to first:

Iterate through SalaryRangeTable, select beginRange and endRange

Then for each entry in that table, I want to be able to:

```
SELECT id FROM UserInfoTable WHERE salary > beginRange AND salary < endRange
```

Therefore, my result set will include all the UserInfoTable id's that have that range.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are just beginning with sql - try to avoid thinking in terms of iterations.. think in terms of joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select s.beginRange, s.endRange, u.id
from SalaryRange s
inner join UserInfo u on u.salary > s.beginRange AND u.salary < s.endRange
```

Comment: Note that `between` does inclusive comparisons, not exclusive.

Comment: Query modified to not be inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select id from userInfoTable u
Where Exists (Select * From salaryRangeTable
              Where u.Salary Between
                      BeginRange and endRange)
```

If you need exclusive comparisons, then use > and <

```
Select id from userInfoTable u
Where Exists (Select * From salaryRangeTable
              Where u.Salary > BeginRange 
                And u.Salary < endRange)
```

Comment: Note that `between` does inclusive comparisons, not exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to join the tables, and use `distinct` to get rid of duplicates from overlapping ranges:

```
select distinct u.id
from SalaryRange s
inner join UserInfo u on u.salary > s.beginRange and u.salary < s.endRange
```